# Issue with incrementing index Counter inside useEffect Hook in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

In this part of code, I try to take a state variable 'lastIndex' and try to increment it using setlastIndex but the value of lastIndex doesn't increment and remains 0 . I am new to React Hooks, please help me. If such an exact query already been asked before in stack overflow then please send the link.

```
function App() {
  const [myAppointment, setmyAppointment] = useState([])
  **const [lastIndex, setlastIndex] = useState(0)** 
  const [orderBy, setorderBy] = useState('petName')
  const [orderDir, setorderDir] = useState('asc')
  const [queryText, setqueryText] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('./data.json')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(result=>{
        **const apts=result.map(item=>{
          item.aptId = lastIndex
          setlastIndex(lastIndex => lastIndex+1)
          return item
        })**
        setmyAppointment(apts)
      })
  },[])
```

Comment: I also tried doing  item.aptId = setlastIndex(lastIndex => lastIndex+1)  but that also doesnt work to increment my lastIndex and actually I have a data.json file in which I have no ids mentioned so i want to create unique id for each object inside the data.json file. For that i have written this setLastIndex code but it only gives me index 0 for all the objects in my data.json file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! I think you sould not use a useState hook inside a map, you should build the new state value in map (in your case Array.reduce may be a better choice), then call setlastIndex only once : setlastIndex(newValue). You could console.log it before to make sure what's happening.

Comment: How can i use Array.reduce ?

Comment: Start here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that `lastIndex` doesnt increase each time you call `setlastIndex` function, so just declare it outside loop and increase each time assigning to aptId property. And after loop set state with the last value

```
then(result=>{
  let currentIndex = lastIndex
  result.forEach(item=>{
    item.aptId = ++currentIndex
  })
  setmyAppointment(result)
  setlastIndex(currentIndex)
})
```

`map` is not needed, you can use result to save it in `setmyAppointments`

Comment: I want new index for a new item that I add to the list , but using lastIndex doesn't provide new index to every new object made using a form. There is again a clash of indexes , if you can help me out ,what can I do fr that?

Comment: ```const addAppointment=(apt)=>{
      let tempApt = myAppointment
      apt.aptId = lastIndex
      tempApt.unshift(apt)

      setmyAppointment([...tempApt])
  } ```

Comment: @GazalJain, but you dont increase lastIndex, you should increase it and result assign to your peoperty and change state

Comment: I tried to increment lastIndex by using apt.aptIndex = lastIndex+1  but it only increments it once ....but I want dynamic incrementation whenever a new appointment object  gets added to my existing array.

Comment: @GazalJain, you should save it in state also